# how to change the default timezone in the ocp cluster(not in the pod level i want to change in the cluster wide ) 4.10 or above

Tags: openshift

HOW TO CHANGE THE DEFAULT TIMEZONE IN THE OCP(OPENSHIFT)  CLUSTER(NOT IN THE POD LEVEL I WANT TO CHANGE IN THE CLUSTER WIDE ) 4.10 OR ABOVE

I'm trying to change the timezone in the cluster but i can't find any links or any help from any document / blobs

can someone please help me (I'm not expecting the env and TZ AND SOME TIME ZONE (I.E., THIS IS FOR POD LEVEL BUT I DONT WANT THIS I'M EXPECTING IN THE WHOLE CLUSTER LEVEL(i.e., **i want to change the timezone for all the workload in the cluster level** ))